# Adding json response to a Map field Mongoose Node

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm just starting out whit node and mongoose and I'm trying to create a user, then create a stripe customer with a stripe generated id and save the response in a user Map field `stripeDetails`.
Here is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    photoUrl: { type: String, required: true },
    phoneNumber: { type: String, required: false },
    address: { type: String, required: false },
    zipCode: { type: String, required: false },

    city: { type: String, required: true },
    region: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },

    isVerified: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
    lastLogin: { type: Number, required: false, default: Date.now },
    
    stripeDetails: {type: Map, required: false}
},
    { timestamps: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'Users');
```

I tried setting the `stripeDetails` field like

```
.then(stripeCustomer => {
                    console.log('Stripe.customer.create', stripeCustomer);

                    result.set('stripeDetails', stripeCustomer);
                    result.save();
...
```

but is not working.. I settle to update the record's field but is a bit messy..

```
exports.createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.body;
    console.log('User is :', user);


    /// Creat use in DB
    User.create(
        user,
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Mongoose createUser error: ', err);
                res.statut(503).send({ error: "Internal error" });
                return;
            }
            console.log('Mongoose createUser: ', result);
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "User created successfully!",
                data: result
            });

            /// Create stripe customer
            stripe.customers.create({

                "address": {
                    "city": user.city,
                    "state": user.region,
                    "country": user.country,
                    "postal_code": user.zipCode

                },
                "balance": 0,
                "created": Date.now,
                "email": user.email,
                "name": user.name,
                "phone": user.phoneNumber,
                "preferred_locales": [],
                "shipping": null,
                "tax_exempt": "none"

            })
                .then(stripeCustomer => {
                    console.log('Stripe.customer.create', stripeCustomer);

                    // save stripe details to db

                    //not working..
                    // result.set('stripeDetails', stripeCustomer);
                    // result.save();


                    // working
                    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                        result.id,
                        {stripeDetails: stripeCustomer},
                        { new: true },
                        function(err, result) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log('Stripe customer not updated to db: ', err);
                            }
                            if (result != null){
                            console.log('Stripe customer updated to DB', result);

                            } else {
                                console.log('Stripe customer to update not found in db ');
                            }
                        }
                    );



                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Stripe.customer.create error: ', error);
                });


        }
    );
};
```

also I can't access the `stripeDetails.id` value for when I need to delete the user..

```
exports.deleteUserById = async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    User.findByIdAndDelete(
        id,
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Mongoose deleteUserById error: ', err);
                res.statur(505).send({ errro: "Internal error" });
            }
            if (result != null) {
                console.log('Mongoose deleteUserById: ', result);
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: "User found!",
                    data: result
                });

                console.log('stripe id is:  ', result.stripeDetails['id']);

                stripe.customers.del(`${result.stripeDetails['id']}`)
                    .then(stripeCustomer => {
                        console.log('Stripe.customer.delete', stripeCustomer);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log('Stripe.customer.delete error: ', error);
                    });



            } else {
                console.log("Mongoose deleteUserById: user not found");
                res.status(404).send({ message: "User not found" });

            }

        });
}
```

I could use the mongoose `_id` as the stripe `id` but I rather use their own separate id generators and keep the ids separate, and get used to work with maps in mongoose. Can you see what I'm doing wrong with in writing and reading `stripeDetails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `stripeDetails` in Schema to be of type `Object`:

```
stripeDetails: {type: Object, required: false}
```

Now you can do this:

```
.then(stripeCustomer => {
  result.stripeDetails.details = stripeCustomer;
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(result.id, result).then((result)=>{
    console.log('User updated.');
  })
})
```

Note that when you are using `Map` as a type, you should access the value of a key with `.get()`. So try to access `stripe_id` like this:

```
let stripe_id = result.stripeDetails.get("id");

stripe.customers.del(stripe_id)
  .then(stripeCustomer => {
    console.log('Stripe.customer.delete', stripeCustomer);
  }) 
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Stripe.customer.delete error: ', error);
  });
```

Check it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps).

Comment: O I see.. great.. I'll give it a try. For the saving of the `stripeDetails` Map field why `result.set('stripeDetails', stripeCustomer);   result.save();` throws an error??Create is not returning an object?

Comment: Is `stripe.customers.create` `Stripe` API? Did you try to `console.log(stripeCustomer)`? What is the result?

Comment: And can I ask why you store `stripeDetails` as type `Map`? You can store it as type `Object` and it will make querying db and setting it more easily.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try it? Also, I would like to tell you that I checked and both `findByIdAndDelete` and `findByIdAndRemove` will return the document in the callback. So, you don't have to replace it.

Comment: indeed I'm using the  Stripe API.  I'm not sure why but `result.set('stripeDetails', stripeCustomer);   result.save();`it now works as expected the get request shows `stripeDetails` field correctly populated with data ..so no need to `findOneAndUpdate()` anymore... when deleting I get 
`stripe id is:   undefined
Stripe.customer.delete error:  Error: Stripe: Argument "id" must be a string, but got: undefined (on API request to `DELETE /customers/{id}`)`

Comment: Hey, since I didn't work with `Map` as a Mongoose type, I checked Mongoose Docs, and it seams that if you are using `Map`, you should access it's values with `.get()`.

Comment: Great.. the field as a map was the problem.. changed to Object and it works as expected. Many thanks. Still wanna understand How to work with maps.. so getting a map value updating a map value..

Comment: I updated my answer again with what I would try with `Map` when fetching `stripe_id`, so maybe you can that? Also I posted the link of Docs so you can check that and see more datails.

Comment: Hi, so indeed is finally sorted..
If working with `Object` then `stripe.customers.del(result.stripeDetails.id)` is correct. When working with `Map` `const stripeId = result.stripeDetails.get("id");`  `stripe.customers.del(stripeId)` is correct. Many thanks again